# How to read a text file, parse it to a web interface and store changes

Tags: html, node.js, parsing, fs

I am looking for a way to read an unformatted UTF-8 text file from disc and parse its content to fields on a web page / web interface, allowing a user to make edits and in return, store these edits to the text file.

The text file and the web interface will be running on a Raspberry Pi 3. I am very new to this, so I'm basically looking for any starting point or even hint, if my approach is heading in the right direction.

As for now, I have considered using Node.js with the [File System Module](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html), which unfortunately only gets me as far as reading the text file. My question therefore mainly aims towards:

1. is node.js the right approach for this scenario?
2. if so, how can i parse individual blocks of this text file to a web interface and ...
3. ... store edits on this web interface back to my file

thanks a lot

Comment: So basically, you want to write a CRUD API for a flat-file database in Node.js and then make a front-end for that API. I imagine there are many tutorials and examples on the Internet demonstrating just that. Maybe look for something like "node.js flat file database CRUD API" and then look for tutorials that use any SPA framework to make a front-end for an API.

Comment: perfect! that's a lot of keywords i had been missing :) thank you very much, @fardjad

Comment: You're welcome :)
This might help you with the API part:
https://medium.com/@etiennerouzeaud/how-create-an-api-restfull-in-express-node-js-without-database-b030c687e2ea